# Como hacer un href con un condicional a otra página PHP

Tags: php

tengo una página que se llama nuevo_producto.php 
Tengo un boton para ir atrás, ¿cómo hago una condicional para que si el el rol del usuario es administrador me lleve a homeadministrador.php, si es secretaria me lleve a la pagina_secretaria.php o si es bodeguero me lleve a pagina_bodeguero.php.

yo intenté algo así, pero soy muy nuevo en esto y no me dió.

```
<a href="<?php if($_SESSION['rol']=="Administrador"){
        header('location:homeadministrador.php');
      } else if($_SESSION['rol']=="Bodeguero") {
        header('location:pagina_bodeguero.php');
      } else {
        header('location:pagina_secretaria.php');
      } ?>"><button class="btn btn-danger">Ir Atrás</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola colega intenta esto.

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['rol']=="Administrador"){
     echo '<a href="homeadministrador.php">Atras</a>';
    }
    if($_SESSION['rol']=="Bodeguero"){
         echo '<a href="pagina_bodeguero.php">Atras</a>';
        }
    if($_SESSION['rol']=="Secretaria"){ 
     echo '<a href="pagina_secretaria.php">Atras</a>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con un switch tmb

```
switch($_SESSION['rol']){
    case: 'Administrador':
      <a href="homeadministrador.php">Atras</a>
    break;
    case: 'bloguero':
      <a href="pagina_administrador.php">Atras</a>
    break;
    default:
      <a href="homeadministrador.php">Atras</a>
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al usar el tag de "a" y el tag de "button" al mismo tiempo, sería mejor usar sólo el tag del botón y un poco de javascript para mantener la interfaz gráfica que estás deseando. Pego ejemplo de como podría usarse:

```
<?php
switch($_SESSION['rol']){
    case 'Administrador':
        echo '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick="javascript:document.location.href = \'homeadministrador.php\';">Ir Atrás</button>';
    break;
    case 'Bodeguero':
        echo '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick="javascript:document.location.href = \'pagina_bodeguero.php\';">Ir Atrás</button>';
    break;
    case 'Secretaria':
        echo '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick="javascript:document.location.href = \'pagina_secretaria.php\';">Ir Atrás</button>';
    break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas formas de lograr lo que quieres, yo en lo personal partiría de un *default* que en tu caso es `pagina_secretaria.php` a lo específico, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$ruta = 'pagina_secretaria.php';

if ($_SESSION['rol'] == 'Administrador') {
    $ruta = 'homeadministrador.php';
}

if ($_SESSION['rol'] == 'Bodeguero') {
    $ruta = 'pagina_bodeguero.php';
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo $ruta ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Ir atrás</a>
```

Como dije hay muchas formas de lograr lo que deseas, yo prefiero esta porque siento que es mas legible, y podemos agregar mas rutas facilmente si luego el proyecto lo llegase a necesitar.

#### Importante

Esto no evitará que si un usuario con rol secretaría viene de la página `homeadministrador.php` y le de click en el botón de atrás del navegador lo lleve `homeadministrador.php`, o si pongo directamente la url en el navegador me lleve a cualquiera de las otras páginas, deberías validar tus permisos en el servidor antes de mostrar diferentes páginas para diferentes roles